# .net platform for automotive

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

I'm looking to write my own software on the .net platform that I can run in my car.

- Beed to package the form factor in a way that I could install in the dashboard or out of sight
- Need to support lcd panel
- Need to support a wifi connection to my home network when parked at home
- Support low power usage when car is off
- Support external storage, likely ssd
- I would like to leverage existing software for media playback - audio mostly, video isn't a concern for me.

Would I be looking at a platform that can run .net embedded, or full .net?  Any suggestions on hardware platform as well?

Comment: It seems that the .NET embedded mechanism is called the "Micro Framework."  I'm not sure you really need it though.  There are numerous Mini-ITX chassis that are designed to take power from a car, allowing you to use plain old x86/x64 on an industry-standard motherboard.

Comment: @Charles, good suggestion.  I am betting Mini-ITX is the way to go.  I think other options are limited.  Found a great case,  hopefully I can find low power hardware

Comment: Doing this stuff in C is trivial. You dont need .NET.

Comment: one place to look some mini-itx solutions is http://www.mini-box.com/Car-PC-Automotive-Computing-Solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into a micro ITX case with a 12vDC power supply that is designed for automotive use. There is a bunch of that stuff listed here: http://www.mini-box.com/s.nl/sc.8/category.101/.f

The power supplies designed for cars are nice because they will monitor ignition status of the car, and will send a sleep or shutdown signal to the motherboard when you turn off the car.

From there, you can just run normal Win XP or Linux with Mono on it, and use the regular .NET framework, instead of messing with the micro framework.

And of course, put an SSD in the thing, because a spinning mechanical drive won't last long on rough roads :)

Comment: +1 Agreed on the SSD and *very* important with the automotive environment is power conditioning... Had issues with mini-box power solutions and in the end went with custom. They are driving for small, but with power sometimes bigger is better.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using either and iOS device (iTouch, iPhone, or iPad) or an Android device (phone or tablet) programmed using one of the [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/features) applications (Monotouch for .Net or Monodroid for Android).

These apps support a good set of the .Net framework and we have used Monotouch to successfully port a very large .Net windows tablet application to iPad in a very short period of time.

Comment: The trouble is, I don't want to be restricted to the phone/tablet form factor because it would be very difficult to integrate the screen and contriols into the car.  I'd like to be able to purchase the lcd motherboard, etc seperately and package them in a way that makes sense so I can seemlessly integrate them into my car.

Comment: @Jeremy I think you find open source hardware that you can configure to your needs and not live with the phone/tablet form factors.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to go with .NET framework (as you mentioned) then Micro Framework or Compact framework (with Windows CE 6 or Compact 7) would do the job.
Micro framework is less powerful especially when you want to get some display-rich application. It's often run on ARM7 and few with ARM9, but there will be more work involved on your side. Plus is that many boards cost less and can be easily adopted to your needs with add-on boards.

Second choice is Windows Compact7 or Embedded CE which has Compact framework. More powerful but with higher requirements on hardware than MF.

You can try with x86 and go with desktop Windows (or Windows Embedded Standard) and have full .NET framework as well.

For micro framework I would recommend tinyclr.com as they have quite big and very helpful community around it.

If compact framework is the choice the hardware then it really depends on what exactly kind of peripherals you need. For example display resolution, touch interface, keyboard/keypad etc.